# Error activating Interface

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am new to .NET. I am create a internet shop but i have a problems

My Error:

> Error activating IBookRepository No matching bindings are
>   available, and the type is not self-bindable. Activation path:  2)
>   Injection of dependency IBookRepository into parameter repo of
>   constructor of type BooksController  1) Request for BooksController
>
> Suggestions:  1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for
>   IBookRepository.  2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure
>   that the module has been loaded into the kernel.  3) Ensure you have
>   not accidentally created more than one kernel.  4) If you are using
>   constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the
>   constructors parameter name.  5) If you are using automatic module
>   loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.

I using 3 project in Solution I have a interface IBookRepository in c# Class Library Domain and using asp.net mvc in controller

IBookRepository:

```
using Domain.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Domain.Abstract
{
    public interface IBookRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<Book> Books { get; }
    }
}
```

BooksController:

```
using Domain.Abstract;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class BooksController : Controller
    {
        private IBookRepository repository;
        public BooksController(IBookRepository repo)
        {
            repository = repo;
        }

        public ViewResult List()
        {
            return View(repository.Books);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a bindings for all the constructor parameter types:

```
 private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new WebUI.Infrastructure.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
    }
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You still have to define your mappings in the Ninject bindings file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have the first step of dependency injection down, but you need to tell your code what *concrete* class to use when your interface is requested.  To do that you need to create a *binding* for your concrete class.

To do this you need to navigate to your Ninject bindings file and add this:

```
Bind<IBookRepository>().To<NameOfYourClassThatImplementsIBookRepository>();
```

Obviously `NameOfYourClassThatImplementsIBookRepository` should be replaced with the actual name of your concrete class (i.e the class that implements your interface).

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me)

Answer (score -1):

I am not aware of Ninject, but looking at the code above, BookController constructor needs an instance of class which implements IBookRepository. Think of constructor chaining or have one more default constructor to pass instance to above written constructor.

```
using Domain.Abstract;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class BooksController : Controller
    {
        private IBookRepository repository;

public BooksController():this(new BookRepository())
        {

        }
        public BooksController(IBookRepository repo)
        {
            repository = repo;
        }

        public ViewResult List()
        {
            return View(repository.Books);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is BookRepository ?

Comment: Concrete class which implements IBookRepository

Comment: OP is clearly using dependency injection, your answer completely removes that.